# ajax post request to view

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to make a simple ajax request to a view but keep having a not Found error for the given url:

```
Not Found: /myapp/start_session/1/scan_ports/
"POST /myapp/start_session/1/scan_ports/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5711
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'scan_ports/',
            data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
            success: function (data) {
                 alert("OK!");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                 alert("NOT OK!");
            }
        });
    });
```

**url**

```
url(r'^scan_ports/$',views.ScanPorts,name='scan_ports'),
```

**view**

```
 @login_required
    def ScanPorts(request):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            currentSetting = models.UserSetting.objects.filter(isCurrent=True)
            if currentSetting.serialPort:
                print("GOT IT!")
            return HttpResponse('')
```

Is the ajax request not set properly?

Comment: Please post the project urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the "myapp" app, replace:

```
method: 'POST',
url: 'scan_ports/',
```

for this:

```
method: 'POST',
url: '/myapp/scan_ports/',
```

Comment: Hi @Gianmar. I realised that changing the ulr to `./scan_ports/` would do the trick to get the relative url. Still the Not Found error persists.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, Can you paste the complete error here please.

Comment: `Not Found: /myapp/start_session/1/scan_ports/` and the js is loaded from the url `/myapp/start_session/1`

Comment: The correct url post is: /myapp/scan_ports, NOT /myapp/start_session/1/scan_ports/

Answer (score 0):

First check your urls, the url on which you posted is incorrect hence 404 not found error.

Try to define your url in your JS as: {% url 'scan_ports' %} which will search your urls with the name your provided in urls.py

In addition, this may not be a good approach to submit a form via ajax.

Your JS should be something like this:

```
$('.form-class-name').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("ajax is called");

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: "/url-name/",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
            },
        error: function(data) {
                alert("Failure");
            }
            })
        }
```

- e.preventDefault() prevents the natural/default action, and prevents from submitting the form twice.
- .serialize(), serializes the form data in a json format.
- append a "/" before and after your action url.

Your view must return a dictionary as ajax deals with JSON format.

Edit your view like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    currentSetting = models.UserSetting.objects.filter(isCurrent=True)
        if currentSetting.serialPort:
            print("GOT IT!")
            a = {'data':'success'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(a))
```

This will return a dictionary required by the ajax.